# Sequence of indiscernibles in in saturated model.

Tags: model-theory

> Let $\lambda > \aleph_{0}$  and M a $\lambda$-saturated structure. Show that
>   for every non-algebraic $\phi(x,a)$ with parameters from $M$ there exists a
>   sequence of indiscernibles $I \subset \phi(M,a)$ of cardinality $\lambda$.

As  $\phi(x,a)$ is not as algebraic then $\phi(x,a)$ is infinite, because it must be sized $\lambda$?

Whenever any $\lambda$-saturated model $M$ I can find a succession of indiscernible of size $\lambda$?

Is it possible to remove the saturation assumption from the previous statement?

Answer (score 1):

It is not *because* it must be sized $\lambda$. It is infinite by the definition of a non-algebraic formula. And it is not $\phi(x,a)$ that is infinite, but $\phi(M,a)$.

You can construct recursively a sequence of indiscernibles of size $\lambda$. First, you can find one of length $\omega$ by Ramsey and compactness and $\aleph_1$-saturation. Then, you can add one more by compactness and $\lambda$-saturation, until you have a sequence of length $\lambda$.

No, it is not possible to remove the saturation from the previous statement. For example, if $M$ is countable, there are no uncountable (nonconstant) indiscernible sequences in it.